# Spark SQL and detecting anomalies in time-series data

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I have some time-series data and let's say that model looks like this:

```
data {
    date: Date,
    greenPoint: Double,
    redPoint: Double,
    anomalyDetected: Boolean
}
```

Let's say that if red point is under specific threshold I want to mark it as anomaly.

I can easily load this data set (I'm using Spark SQL with Elastic, so I have here DataFrame to be more specific) and mark some data as anomaly, but how can I group them after that, or at least count how many anomalies were detected?

If I could somehow add to each anomaly some unique ID (generated when anomaly flag is changing) then I would easily group them even in Elastic query.
It would be great also to have start anomaly date and end anomaly date in these grouped data.

Basically my goal is to in below example detect five different anomalies (marked in red) and either mark original data to easily group them and display on UI or produce list contains five elements (five anomalies, with some additional fields like start and end date etc.).

[image: graph]